# How to pull an ONVIF event from a camera using Java ONVIF web services

Tags: java, web-services, onvif

In order to pull events from Axis camera using ONVIF, I've created the following:

```java
CreatePullPointSubscriptionResponse pullPointSubscriptionResponse = event.createPullPointSubscription(parameters);
PullPointSubscription pullPointSubscription = pullPointSubscriptionResponse.getSubscriptionReference().getPort(PullPointSubscription.class);
PullMessages pullMessagesParameters = new PullMessages();
pullMessagesParameters.setMessageLimit(1);
javax.xml.datatype.Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.createDuration("PT1M");
pullMessagesParameters.setTimeout(duration);
try {

    PullMessagesResponse pullMessageResponse =
        pullPointSubscription.pullMessages(pullMessagesParameters);
} catch (PullMessagesFaultResponse_Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int d = 1;
catch(TopicNotSupportedFault | TopicExpressionDialectUnknownFault | InvalidTopicExpressionFault
    | InvalidMessageContentExpressionFault | InvalidProducerPropertiesExpressionFault
    | UnacceptableInitialTerminationTimeFault | NotifyMessageNotSupportedFault | ResourceUnknownFault
    | UnsupportedPolicyRequestFault | InvalidFilterFault | SubscribeCreationFailedFault
    | UnrecognizedPolicyRequestFault e)

{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My problem is that when pullMessages is executed, the web service is created with SOAP1.1, while the camera expects SOAP1.2 (I get version mismatch error response).

The createPullPointSubscription creates a good version web service, since I've created is with JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and i've set the binding myself.
I cannot create the pull messages WS the same way, because I don't have the reference points that are encapsulated into the pullPointSubscription object (and they are private).

I'm looking for a way to let PullPointSubscription be aware of the current SOAP version, so I'll be able to receive the event response.

Comment: Where did you get the WSDL file to create this? I'm using https://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/event.wsdl but the generated classes are completely different for what I can see in the few examples I've found.

Comment: It was quite a long time ago, so I don't remember clearly. I'm pretty sure though it was from onvif.org official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem in a bit of a workaround.
I've extracted the private parameters from the response using .toString(), parsed the string, extracted the parameters, and created a new PullPointSubscription object with the right version and parameters.